# Match multiple occurrences of a line that starts with a character

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that matches a line that starts with optional whitespace, `<`, a bunch of stuff, and then `>`. For example, this whole thing should be matched 3 times:

```
<div
    data-test="foo"
    class="first bar baz"
>
   <h2>test</h2>
</div>
```

I have that working and it uses the following regex: `(^\s*<.*?>\s*$)+`. Check it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/wLa0NM/1/).

However, it currently works by generating three matches. Is there a way to make adjacent lines that are matched return as one match?

In the above example, since everything is matched, I want it to return as a single match. Can that happen?

**Edit:** To clarify - the regex should match:

```
<foo>
```

also

```
    <h1>test</h1>
```

and even

```
  <   b-8253j'\sf>
```

but ignore

```
foo<bar>
```

because it doesn't effectively start with `<`.

If there is no `>` found on the same line, it continues to match all lines until it reaches `>`:

```
   <div
   matches
   here>but this line is also matched</div>
```

---

As I said, my regex does that. However, it would match this:

```
<div>
<foo></foo>
<baaaar>
```

Three different times. Since everything is matched, I want those matches to be combined and returned as a single match.

However, if the middle line, for example, is not valid, it should return 2 matches:

```
<div>         // match 1
no<foo></foo> // doesn't start with `<`, ignored
<baaaar>      // match 2
```

Comment: *"should be matched 3 times"*: 4 times? according to your description `</h2>` would also match.

Comment: If your goal is to recognise HTML, then regex is not the right tool.

Comment: No, it should match the whole line once. The starting `<h2>` to start the match and the ending `</h2>` to end the match. The regex I provided does what I want. I just want to combine adjacent matches that it generates.

Comment: Then your first paragraph description is not correct as it would allow just `<h2>` to match.

Comment: Yes, I want that too. The regex does what I need. I want to combine the resulting matches if they are adjacent.

Comment: Your `<h2>` is not adjacent to `</h2>`. It really looks like you want to implement something that is HTML aware. regex is not the right tool for that.

Comment: Please, open the link I provided. The regex would match three three things that are adjacent to each other. I want to return them as one match. I want to match singular tags on one line, opened and closed tags on one line, even `<foobar>`,  and allow for multiline only when the tag is closed on another line. I also know that regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML. I'm experimenting.

Comment: @trincot I edited my question to clarify what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a lazy match (match least possible substring). Remove the question mark and it'll attempt a greedy one (match largest possible substring) instead:
`(^\s*<.*>\s*$)+`

But generally processing HTML using regexes will lead you down a painful road.

Comment: This would also match lines that have a character before the initial `<`. As seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/wLa0NM/2).

Comment: If you wish to keep some substrings which match and discard others that don't match, the task is really string manipulation. Regex alone doesn't do that.

Try sed with back references.